# Stock spread: wide vs. narrow?

Tags: stocks, spreads

At [First Time Investor - Stock market spreads](http://www.thefti.com/stockmarketspreads.html), the author states:

> For smaller companies the spread can
>   be as wide as 15-20pc.  That means the
>   shares would have to go up as much
>   20pc before you start making a profit.

Why is that? If I am a buyer and I buy at 1 $ and sell at 1.02, I make a profit irrespective of the spread. No?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the *bid* and *ask* prices dictate what you can buy and sell at (at market, at least), and the difference between the two, or *spread*, contributes implicitly to your gains or losses. For example, say your $1 stock actually had a bid of $0.90 and an ask of $1.10; i.e. say that $1 was the last price. You would have to buy the stock at the ask price of $1.10, but now you can only sell that stock at the bid price of $0.90. Thus, you would need to make at least that $0.20 spread before you can make a profit.